# Docker.Service Failing to Start on Manjaro XFCE Linux

Tags: linux, docker, manjaro

I'm having problems getting docker to run on Manjaro XFCE.

I've installed it with:

`sudo pacman -Syu`

`sudo pacman -S docker`

And attempted to run it with:

`sudo systemctl start docker.service`

But it is failing with this error:

```
Job for docker.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status docker.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

and this is the log I get with `systemctl status docker.service`:

```
[nimbi@nimbi-manjaro ~]$ systemctl status docker.service
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2020-10-29 01:31:09 MST; 14min ago
TriggeredBy: ● docker.socket
       Docs: https://docs.docker.com
    Process: 14837 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 14837 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Oct 29 01:31:09 nimbi-manjaro systemd[1]: docker.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 3.
Oct 29 01:31:09 nimbi-manjaro systemd[1]: Stopped Docker Application Container Engine.
Oct 29 01:31:09 nimbi-manjaro systemd[1]: docker.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Oct 29 01:31:09 nimbi-manjaro systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Oct 29 01:31:09 nimbi-manjaro systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
```

`journalctl -xe` shows this:

```
░░ The job identifier is 4697.
Oct 29 01:31:09 nimbi-manjaro systemd[1]: docker.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Oct 29 01:31:09 nimbi-manjaro systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
░░ Subject: Unit failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://forum.manjaro.org/c/support
░░ 
░░ The unit docker.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
Oct 29 01:31:09 nimbi-manjaro systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
░░ Subject: A start job for unit docker.service has failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://forum.manjaro.org/c/support
░░ 
░░ A start job for unit docker.service has finished with a failure.
░░ 
░░ The job identifier is 4631 and the job result is failed.
Oct 29 01:31:09 nimbi-manjaro systemd[1]: docker.socket: Failed with result 'service-start-limit-hit'.
░░ Subject: Unit failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://forum.manjaro.org/c/support
░░ 
░░ The unit docker.socket has entered the 'failed' state with result 'service-start-limit-hit'.
lines 1990-2012/2012 (END)
```

Attempting to run it manually responds with:

```
[nimbi@nimbi-manjaro ~]$ /usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock
INFO[2020-10-29T01:53:00.526035448-07:00] Starting up                                  
dockerd needs to be started with root. To see how to run dockerd in rootless mode with unprivileged user, see the documentation
[nimbi@nimbi-manjaro ~]$ sudo /usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock
INFO[2020-10-29T01:53:08.550576442-07:00] Starting up                                  
failed to load listeners: no sockets found via socket activation: make sure the service was started by systemd
```

Anyone know how to fix this?

I've also attempted reinstalling via the AUR package but I get the exact same problem.

I'm on Manjaro XFCE 20.1.2 if it helps.

---EDIT---

I think I figured it out...

I had to use `sudo systemctl enable docker.service` and then type `reboot` to let it auto start itself.

It is running now.

Here is my current `systemctl status docker.service` command output:

```
[nimbi@nimbi-manjaro ~]$ systemctl status docker.service
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor p>
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2020-10-29 02:09:12 MST; 3min 10s ago
TriggeredBy: ● docker.socket
       Docs: https://docs.docker.com
   Main PID: 946 (dockerd)
      Tasks: 15
     Memory: 72.9M
     CGroup: /system.slice/docker.service
             └─946 /usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/cont>

Oct 29 02:09:10 nimbi-manjaro dockerd[946]: time="2020-10-29T02:09:10.29207978>
Oct 29 02:09:10 nimbi-manjaro dockerd[946]: time="2020-10-29T02:09:10.29210347>
Oct 29 02:09:10 nimbi-manjaro dockerd[946]: time="2020-10-29T02:09:10.36927019>
Oct 29 02:09:11 nimbi-manjaro dockerd[946]: time="2020-10-29T02:09:11.20664981>
Oct 29 02:09:11 nimbi-manjaro dockerd[946]: time="2020-10-29T02:09:11.50144324>
Oct 29 02:09:11 nimbi-manjaro dockerd[946]: time="2020-10-29T02:09:11.96303711>
Oct 29 02:09:11 nimbi-manjaro dockerd[946]: time="2020-10-29T02:09:11.96351080>
Oct 29 02:09:11 nimbi-manjaro dockerd[946]: time="2020-10-29T02:09:11.97714186>
Oct 29 02:09:12 nimbi-manjaro dockerd[946]: time="2020-10-29T02:09:12.58058471>
Oct 29 02:09:12 nimbi-manjaro systemd[1]: Started Docker Application Container
```

Comment: can you provide all the error logs?

Comment: Just added the `journalctl -xe` logs and error message. Not sure what other logs there are tbh.

Comment: the logs from `systemctl status docker.service` are cut off. try to stop the service, purge the /var/lib/docker folder and then restart. BTW, did you already try to reboot the system after upgrading it?

Comment: I have restarted. but that's all the `systemctl status docker.service` shows for me. and as for purging the `/var/lib/docker/` folder I've tried that as well and it still has this problem. Thus why I finally came here. Albeit I probably should have mentioned that in my post. sorry for that lack of information.

Comment: already tried to execute the dockerd manually? `/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock`

Comment: Just tried that one now. It failed as well. I'll update the main post with the response right now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223805/discussion-between-joshua-lewis-and-stefano).

Comment: Have you mounted `-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock` when `docker run`?

Comment: I think that is done already... it responds with `Docker version 19.03.13, build 4484c46
` when i run `docker -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock`

Comment: aaand now it's running. ok I think I figured it out. I had to make systemctl auto start it by enabling it. Trying to run it myself was what kept failing.